# Writing a CASE statement to return values based on dates in a single record

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, case

I assuming my solution to this is some kind of CASE statement but feel free to suggest alternatives.

Our company works in 4 week periods and we have a table with fields as follows (apologies for displaying it this way, I tried a few other methods and it looked horrific):

- period
- startDate - start date of the period
- endDate - end date of the period
- w1_end - end date of the 1st week of the period
- w2_end - end date of the 2nd week of the period
- w3_end - end date of the 3rd week of the period

I have a second table containing a populated date field, and empty period and week fields that I need to populate based on the data in the above field.

I can get the period field in the second table updated easily enough but can't work out how to UPDATE it to put a 1,2,3 or 4 in the week field based on whether date falls in the 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th week in a period.  I've started on a few ideas but it becomes obvious as I write more that it's not going to work.  Hopefully this makes sense.  One option I guess would be for me to ignore the wx_end fields and just use between start_date and start date + 7 then week 1  kind of ideas?

Please could someone suggest a way to do this (redesigning the period table isn't going to be possible!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update using a join and a case will do what you want... quick and dirty code... switch the dates to be what your column names are

```
UPDATE table2 
  set table2.period = table1.period,
      table2.weekfield = CASE
         WHEN table2.datefield between table1.date1 and table1.date2 then 1
         WHEN table2.datefield between table1.date2 and table1.date3 then 2
         WHEN table2.datefield between table1.date3 and table1.date4 then 3
         ELSE NULL
         END
  from table2 
  inner join table1 on (whatever)
  where table2 (whatever)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much.  It does exactly what I needed.  With hindsight (and someone else telling me the answer!) it seems simple.